# How to set input as a name for a variable in java?

Tags: java, variables, input

```
System.out.print(">> ");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String input = br.readLine();
```

I would like to name a variable (double input=new double[5];) with the name the program gets from BufferedReader. How to do that?

Comment: What do you want it for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it. Variable are defined at compile-time. And you don't need it - how would you access variables with dynamic names?

You can use a `Map<String, double[]>` to map a string to a double array. `map.put(name, array)` and then `map.get(name)` will give you the array.

Comment: No. Code-generation and byte-code manupulation - maybe, if it's a about fields. But with local variables it may be nearly impossible (haven't tried it, but I wouldn't)

Comment: definitely byte code manipulation, checkout javassit. Don't know why you would want to do that though.

Comment: Javaassist lets you do local modifications as well. But of course, not sure why you would want that. Unless, you are trying to do something like a interactive console. Like irb or something.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. It would be equivalent of changing the source code at run-time. Why do you need to do this, anyway?